How to set up fingerprint confirmation for deletion (or modification) of anything on the phone
A number of things can be deleted unwantedly in households where people share a phone or have a person taking care of another person and as such grab a hold of their phone, regularly.
I wonder whether there is a way to set up, globally, fingerprint confirmation for all deletions of anything on the phone (and requiring fingerprint confirmation to remove such support if desired). This could be a solution to the problem.
I am tired of having WhatsApp messages, emails, documents, and other files on the system and in the cloud removed unwantedly, just to get back to that later, and find it is not there.
Where can I find this solution in the settings?

If you want to have a deletion confirmation of an element within an app like a message in Whatsapp then the app is responsible for implementing such a check. From Android perspective there is just the app and it's data. If the data is one video or thousands of messages is unknown to Android. => talk to Facebook/Meta
